# How create some variable with dynamic and static elements in one part in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i create some variables with dynamic and static elements in one part together in python loop? Something like this:

Static part: `self.var_li_`. Dynamic part: `da`

```
for da in range(10):
   self.var_li_da = da
```

And my output would be:

```
var is : self.var_li_1 and value : 1
var is : self.var_li_2 and value : 2
var is : self.var_li_3 and value : 3
var is : self.var_li_4 and value : 4
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
for da in range(10):
    setattr(self, 'var_li_{}'.format(da), da)
```

Comment: Thx, solved!! i use setattr this way :for da in range(10):
    setattr(self, 'var_li_%s' %da, da) and not work, can i ask why ?

Comment: @alireza.m Glad it helped :) I prefer `format` instead of `%` for string interpolation, but both ways work for me in Python 3.3.

Comment: thx, maybe i was wrong, i found this way too and it's work, but this way is right to use (because of exec)? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7422918/1170846

Comment: @alireza.m The problem with `exec` is that you can execute arbitrary code, and that is something risky when you use string interpolation. Here it doesn't matter, but `setattr` is more natural in this context (setting an object attribute).